# Database Transaction in @KafkaListener method

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-data, spring-kafka

I'm reading a ton of questions and answers about this topic, but I can't solve my problem.

I initialized a Springboot project with Kafka and spring-data-jdbc.
What I'm trying to do is

1. Configure a Kafka JDBC Connector in order to push record changes from a PostgreSQL DB into a Kafka topic
2. Setup a Kafka Consumer in order to consume records pushed into the topic by inserting them into another PostgresSQL DB.

For point 1 is everything ok.
For point 2 I'm having some problem.

This is how is organized the project

```
com.migration
 - MigrationApplication.java
com.migration.config
 - KafkaConsumerConfig.java
com.migration.db
 - JDBCConfig.java
 - RecordRepository.java
com.migration.listener
 - MessageListener.java
com.migration.model
 - Record.java
 - AbstractRecord.java
 - PostgresRecord.java
```

This is the `MessageListener` class

```
@EnableJdbcRepositories("com.migration.db")
@Transactional
@Configuration
public class MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private RecordRepository repository;

    @KafkaListener(topics={"author"}, groupId = "migrator", containerFactory = "migratorKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenGroupMigrator(Record record) {
        repository.insert(message);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

I think is pretty clear, it setup a Kafka Consumer in order to listen on "author" topic and consume the record by inserting it into DB.

As you can see, inside `listenGroupMigrator()` method is performed the insert into DB of the record and then is thrown `RuntimeException` because I'm checking if `@Transactional` works and if rollback is performed.

But not, **rollback is not performed**, even if the class is annotated with `@Transactional`.

For completeness these are other classes

`RecordRepository` class

```
@Repository
public class RecordRepository {
    public RecordRepository() {}

    public void insert(Record record) {
        JDBCConfig jdbcConfig = new JDBCConfig();
        SimpleJdbcInsert messageInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcConfig.postgresDataSource());

        messageInsert.withTableName(record.tableName()).execute(record.content());
    }
}
```

`JDBCConfig` class

```
@Configuration
public class JDBCConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

`KafkaConsumerConfig` class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-server}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    private <T extends Record> ConsumerFactory<String, T> consumerFactory(String groupId, Class<T> clazz) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(clazz));

    }

    private <T extends Record> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, T> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(String groupId, Class<T> clazz) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, T> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(groupId, clazz));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PostgresRecord> migratorKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("migrator", PostgresRecord.class);
    }
}
```

`MigrationApplication` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MigrationApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MigrationApplication.class, args);
        MessageListener listener = context.getBean(MessageListener.class);
    }
}
```

How can I make the `listenGroupMigrator` method transactional?

Comment: Note: This is not "Kafka Connect"

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Kafka per se, it is just about the JDBC transaction. Have you set `@EnableTransactionManagement` on some `@Configuration` class? You need that for the framework to apply `@Transactional`. You can run it in a debugger, put a breakpoint in the listener, and you should see a transaction interceptor in the stack (it is that interceptor that commits or rolls back the transaction).

Comment: I set `@EnableTransactionManagement` on `MessageListener` class or on `JDBCConfig` class but no result. I went in debug mode into `listenGroupMigrator()`, first time the record is inserted, then it's invoked other 10 times with the error that I'm trying to insert a record with the same pk. I see some debug variable referring to interceptors but nothing about a transaction interceptor. What I'm doing wrong?